# byte[] from input file in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How can I get byte[] from:

> < input type="file" value="${restaurant.logo }" name="logo" />
>   in Spring MVC?

I want to have byte[] array to convert it to base64. But I dont know how to simply convert file from input to byte[].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<form action="uploadLogo">
   <input type="file" ... />
</form>
```

and then in the `@Controller`

```
@RequestMapping("/uploadLogo")
public String uploadLogo(@RequestParam MultipartFile logo) {
     byte[] bytes = logo.getBytes();
     String base64 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes), "ISO-8859-2");
}
```

(Base64 is part of [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/))

Comment: how to do this with MultiActionAndView function? I got:
> public ModelAndView myrestaurantadd(HttpServletRequest request,
>    HttpServletResponse response, Restaurant > restaurant)

Comment: just append the method argument to the rest

Comment: When I put requestparam to my arguments, I got error: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile]: Specified class is an interface

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/myrestaurantadd.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView myrestaurantadd(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response, Restaurant restaurant, @RequestParam MultipartFile logo) throws Exception {
  User user = loggedUser.getLoggedUser();
  byte[] bytes = logo.getBytes();
  String base64 = new String(Base64.encode(bytes));
  restaurant.setLogo(base64);
  return new ModelAndView("redirect:mojekonto.htm#box-three");
 }

Comment: hm. try placing it as a first argument (rather than last)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile, which will be able to wrap an upload file out-of-the-box and has a `getBytes()` method to return the file content as `byte[]`.

You can also bind a `byte[]` field to the uploaded file if you really want to -- by simply registering a ByteArrayMultipartFileEditor as custom editor for your binder.